# Android Fb2png native compilation issue

Tags: android, android-ndk

i was tried to compile the android fb2png native source codes using jni. But i am facing the following problems. i have go-ogled but didn't found any solutions . Please help me . have added the ndk issue .

Issue 
**

```
** /cygdrive/d/Android_NDK/android-ndk-r5/ndk-build
ompile thumb  : fb2png <= fb2png.c
ompile thumb  : fb2png <= img_process.c
ompile thumb  : fb2png <= fb.c
xecutable     : fb2png
:/RAJESH-ANDROID/Rajesh-workspace/ZT/obj/local/armeabi/objs/fb2png/img_process.o: In function `save_png':
:/RAJESH-ANDROID/Rajesh-workspace/ZT/jni/img_process.c:182: undefined reference to `png_create_write_struct'
:/RAJESH-ANDROID/Rajesh-workspace/ZT/jni/img_process.c:188: undefined reference to `png_create_info_struct'
:/RAJESH-ANDROID/Rajesh-workspace/ZT/jni/img_process.c:192: undefined reference to `png_set_write_fn'
:/RAJESH-ANDROID/Rajesh-workspace/ZT/jni/img_process.c:193: undefined reference to `png_set_IHDR'
:/RAJESH-ANDROID/Rajesh-workspace/ZT/jni/img_process.c:208: undefined reference to `png_set_bKGD'
:/RAJESH-ANDROID/Rajesh-workspace/ZT/jni/img_process.c:209: undefined reference to `png_write_info'
:/RAJESH-ANDROID/Rajesh-workspace/ZT/jni/img_process.c:211: undefined reference to `png_write_image'
:/RAJESH-ANDROID/Rajesh-workspace/ZT/jni/img_process.c:212: undefined reference to `png_write_end'
:/RAJESH-ANDROID/Rajesh-workspace/ZT/jni/img_process.c:214: undefined reference to `png_destroy_write_struct'
:/RAJESH-ANDROID/Rajesh-workspace/ZT/obj/local/armeabi/objs/fb2png/img_process.o: In function `stdio_write_func':
:/RAJESH-ANDROID/Rajesh-workspace/ZT/jni/img_process.c:132: undefined reference to `png_get_io_ptr'
ollect2: ld returned 1 exit status
ake: *** [/cygdrive/D/RAJESH-ANDROID/Rajesh-workspace/ZT/obj/local/armeabi/fb2png] Error 1 **
```

**

http://code.google.com/p/android-fb2png/source/browse/

My libpng source. 
[image: My Project]

Thanks ,
Rajesh K

Answer (score 2):

You are missing libpng: notice that from the repo there is a static copy of libpng included [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-fb2png/source/browse/#git/libpng/lib). Check that you either have the libpng.a file in your directory or that you pull the libpng source code and setup the makefile for it.

Comment: hi @Femi i have added the libpng file already . i have attached the image in edit like  how i have added  it in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Move all this png.h pngconf.h pngusr.h files in from include to jni folder.